# How to take screenshot using JavaScript using Chrome Dev Tools

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, html2canvas, webpage-screenshot

I am trying to create a chrome extension that includes taking a screenshot of the user's screen. I want to give users the option to select a specific part of the screen like the clipping tool on windows (this is really important for the extension). I have conducted a lot of research on how I can possibly do this by either writing my own code or using an existing service. I have found html2Canvas to be the best solution so far but it takes a pic of the whole screen, not ideal for my case. During my research, I found that chrome dev tools actually contain this feature of taking a screenshot of the specific part of the webpage. Is there a way to access chrome dev tools using JS for my project and prompt the user to select the area? Is there a way to pass this saved image to another service without saving the image on client's computer? Thank you for your help

EDIT: I have looked at [Using HTML5/Canvas/JavaScript to take in-browser screenshots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912092/using-html5-canvas-javascript-to-take-in-browser-screenshots) solution, but none mention chrome dev tools. I already tried using getDisplayMedia() but it takes screenshots of the whole screen.

Comment: Have you considered having the user draw a box, taking the screenshot of the whole page, and then cropping the screenshot to the coordinates of the box?